# how to solve this second kind nonlinear Abel equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting to solve the following second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation (ODE) known as a second kind nonlinear Abel equation:

$$y_{\xi}'y - y = \frac{\delta}{\delta - (1-\delta)(\xi-c)}$$

By making the substitution $y(\xi) = \frac{1}{\omega(\xi)}$, we can transform the given equation into an Abel degenerate nonlinear ODE of the first kind, as shown:

$$\omega_{\xi}' = - \mathcal{F}(\xi) \omega^{3} - \omega^{2}, \quad \mathcal{F}(\xi) = \frac{\delta}{\delta - (1-\delta)(\xi-c)}$$

Despite these transformations, I have been unable to find a solution. I welcome any suggestions or insights that may assist me in solving this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry I am a bit lost with the notation: what does $y_\xi'$ mean?

Comment: I’m sorry for the confusion caused by my statement. $y_{\xi}^{'} = \frac{dy}{d\xi}$.  I want use this notation to denote the function $y$ that depends on the variable $\xi$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Follow up question: I only see one derivative so it is a first order equation, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Do you have a specific domain and boundary condition?

Comment: No, I don't have any additional constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Wolframalpha and Maple both produce a [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%28x%29*y%28x%29-y%28x%29%3D1%2F%28a*x%2Bb%29) for $(a\xi+b)(y'y-y)=1$ involving the error function. Inserting $a=\frac{\delta-1}{\delta}$ and $b=1-c\frac{\delta-1}{\delta}$ yields:

$$
0=\sqrt{2\pi}((c-\xi-1)\delta+\xi-c)\cdot erf\left(\frac{(\delta-1)y(\xi)+(c-\xi-1)\delta-c+\xi}{\sqrt{2\delta(1-\delta)}}\right)+2e^{\frac{((\delta-1)y(\xi)+(c-\xi-1)\delta-c+\xi)^2}{2\delta(1-\delta)}}\sqrt{\delta(1-\delta)}+C_0((c-\xi-1)\delta+\xi-c))
$$

Given the structure of the solution I am fairly certain this can not be reduced and expressed with more simple functions at least not for general $C_0$.

Comment: Wow, this looks so complicated. Thank you for your help！